# STREAMBUILDE with boolean values

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I need to how to handle a stream builder with boolean data.

I need to know how to send bool data to my StreamBuilder in the HomePage,
I was using (!snapshot.hasData) but this method only see if theres data or not no matter if they are true or false.

and i need that know the difference betwen false and true,
to show me a widget only when geolocator returns true and another widget only when it returns false

HOMEPAGE

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final locationService = Provider.of<GeolocatorService>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: locationService.refreshLocation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return _EnableGpsMessage();
              }
              return _AccessButton();
            }));
  }
}





PROVIDER

  bool _gpsEnabled = false;

  bool get gpsEnabled => _gpsEnabled;
  set gpsEnabled(bool value) {
    _gpsEnabled = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  final StreamController _refreshLocation = new StreamController.broadcast();

  Stream get refreshLocation => this._refreshLocation.stream;



  _checkGpsStatus() async {
    final isEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    print('FROM GEOLOCATOR SERVICE $isEnabled');
    // this._refreshLocation.sink.add(isEnabled);

    Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream().listen((event) {
      final statusStream =
          (event.index == 1) ? gpsEnabled = true : gpsEnabled = false;
      print(statusStream);

      this._refreshLocation.sink.add(statusStream);
    });
    // return (!isEnabled) ? gpsEnabled = false : gpsEnabled = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

snapshot.[data](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/data.html) is the one which contains the value (which can be `bool`, `Object`, or something else).

`hasData` is the method to know if `data` is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

The value is in `snapshot.data`:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) { 
  if (snapshot.data ?? false) {
    return TrueWidget();
  }
  else {
    return FalseWidget();
  } 
}
return LoadingWidget();
```